# Convert 2D matrix to 3D using two mapping vectors with categorical values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, multidimensional-array, matrix

A similar question probably has been asked already, but I cannot locate it. Something wrong with me today, that I cannot find a good solution to a kind of frequent problem.

I have M x N matrix of doubles, and two N x 1 vectors (cell arrays of strings) with categorical values. The 1st vector contains K unique values and the 2nd - L unique values, such as K * L >= N.

I would like to convert the original matrix to 3D matrix M x K x L. So, to keep the 1st dimension, the 2nd dimension will correspond to unique values in the 1st vector, and 3rd dimension - to unique values in 2nd vector.

Let's consider that vectors are not sorted. It is guaranteed that there are no duplicate combinations of corresponding elements in two vectors. The matrix values for missing combinations can be 0s.

I can convert categorical vectors to numbers with `grp2idx`, which can be considered as column and page numbers. But how to apply them to the original matrix?

**EDIT:**

Here is some random data:

```
A = reshape(1:24,4,6);
v1 = {'s1','s1','s2','s2','s3','s3'}';
v2 = {'t1','t2','t1','t2','t1','t2'}';
idx = randperm(6); %# just to randomize
v1 = v1(idx);
v2 = v2(idx);
[M, N] = size(z); %# M=4, N=6
K = numel(unique(v1)); %# K=3
L = numel(unique(v2)); %# L=2
```

I need to reshape matrix A to 4x3x2 in such manner that column 1 page 1 will correspond to combination s1_t1, column 2 page 2 to s2_t2, etc. In this example K*L equals N, so all the positions will have the data, but this is not a general case.

Comment: Can you maybe give an example of what the input and output could look like? I have a hard time understanding what will happen with the N columns in the first array, for example.

Comment: I edited the question adding some random data.

Comment: Are the combinations `[v1(i) v2(i)]` guaranteed to be unique? If not, which value from A do you want to write into the corresponding output element? Or should the output be a cell array?

Comment: Yes, guaranteed. I wrote it in the question.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `accumarray` for this. Note that `grp2idx` would give somewhat unexpected results, since it starts numbering at the first unique element it finds, instead of numbering according to sorted values of `v1` or `v2`. If you don't care about order, you can use e.g. `idx2=grp2idx(v1)`.

```
idx1 = ndgrid(1:M,1:N); %# rows
[~,idx2]=ismember(v1,unique(v1)); 
idx2 = repmat(idx2',M,1); 
[~,idx3]=ismember(v2,unique(v2));
idx3 = repmat(idx3',M,1);

out = accumarray([idx1(:),idx2(:),idx3(:)],A(:),[M,K,L],@(x)x,0);
```

Comment: Thank a lot! Works perfect. I actually do care about the order of categorical values to keep them as them appear in the vectors. So, GRP2IDX does exactly what I need: `[idx2,v1unq]=grp2idx(v1);`.